# Why use log per-million count when analyzing corpora?

Tags: logarithm, corpus-linguistics

This might be such a trivial question for you, but please bare with me as I don't have background in statistics. So I am curious about corpus linguistics, and especially in this case how corpora is used to prove the Brevity Law, also known as Zip'f law of abbreviation. Simply put, this theorem postulates that the shorter the words are, the more often they occur in language. Of course, visualization will make a great sense of proving the theorem, so I went across this visualization from Wikipedia:

[image]

The x-axis stands for word character length and the y-axis stands for word count, in log per-million count.

My question is, why using **log per-million count**? Is it for normalization so that the words with lesser counts are well represented in the analysis? Anyone giving an insight to this, as well as some little readings, would greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking why logarithms?  Or why counts?  Or why counts per million?

Comment: Why logarithms and counts per-million

Comment: Logs are *the* way to assess power law relationships like Zipf's law.

Answer (score 0):

Logs will make the graph more readable. In the graph you posted, frequency goes up past 9. It looks like this is log base e (because there are only 2 horizontal lines between 0 and 1, which would be between 1 and ~2.718, and because the frequency of the most common words makes sense on that scale).  Then the peak is about 10,000 per million. On a linear scale, that would make it impossible to distinguish any frequencies lower than about 1,000, but you want to be able to distinguish those.

It has to be parts per *something*. For the shape of the graph, it doesn't much matter what. But log ppm gives nice single digit numbers on the y axis. Those are easy to read.

Also, a log scale seems (by eyeballing) to be a not-bad fit to the most common word at each word length. If you drew a straight line from "the" to "which" to "information" it would be ... sort of right.  If you have the raw data (and not just the Wikipedia page) you could try adding a smooth line to the plot and see how it looks.

Finally, if that line does work, it has a nice interpretation: For each added letter, frequency declines by XX %  (you would have to estimate XX from the data).